# RISCV RV32I Shifting >32 bit using two registers

Tags: c, assembly, riscv

I want to write following C code using RISC V. It should shift a `long long` variable into a single result register.
I have the value `0x181FFDC00` which cannot fit into a 32 bit register. Therefore I have to use two registers to store the value.
A loop should shift the value multiple times, but how would I be able to handle the `0x1` in the second register?

This is what I have for now (not handling the overflow)

```
# long long value = 0x181FFDC00;
# int i = 0;
# do {
#     value = value >> 1;
#     i++;
# } while (i<9);

.globl main
.text

main:
    li s0, 0x181FFDC00      # s0 = 0x81FFDC00
    li s1, 0x0              # s1 = 0 (= i)
    li s2, 0x9              # s2 = 9 (condition for while loop)
        
    do:
        srli s0, s0, 0x1    # s0 = s0 > 1
        addi, s1, s1, 0x1   # i++
        blt s1, s2, do      # while i < 9
```

Comment: You should either write in C and not care about the registers, or write in assembly the way you need it. So what exactly do you need? C or Assembly? You can also have a compiler to turn your C code into Asssembly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have the task to translate the given C code to assembly

Comment: This code has a constant outcome, and can be translated into 3 assembly lines as in https://godbolt.org/z/rnzW4v88G But if you want less optimized code, you can play with optimization levels on the same link (replace `-O3` with `-O0` to `-O2`) and get inspiration from the result.

Comment: You're supposed to use two registers to hold the initial value, so use two registers for that variable.  You get to decide the format of the split into 2 registers the 64-bit value.  So choose some split and store each part into one of the two registers.

Comment: When you shift a value stored in two registers, use the shifted-out bit as the to-be-shifted-in bit of the second register. Use your programmer's manual to look for appropriate instructions.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It actually takes 4 instructions to right-shift a 64-bit integer; your godbolt link just returns a 64-bit constant constructed with three instructions.  https://godbolt.org/z/7frofsWf9 shows `long long foo(long long x) { return x>>1; }` using shifts/OR to get the right low half, 4 total instructions.  Of course, if the only use-case really is with a compile-time constant, then yes you should do constant-propagation through the loop, making this a weird question.  Perhaps they need that constant at each shift offset for something else in the loop.